# how do you make an s3 url expire when it is clicked

Tags: amazon-s3

I can set headers to make a s3 link expire after a certain period of time, but is there a way to make the link expire after it has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that bar removing or renaming the file on S3.

Your only option is to make sure your urls are only valid for a very short time period.

Comment: I just made the link valid for five minutes. Hopefully that works out ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the expiry time with the [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) while generating s3 URLs with it.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i'm trying to figure out how to get the link to expire as soon as it has been clicked, not after a certain period of time.

Comment: One workaroud for this would be to make the download link with a random key and post to a page (eg.download.php)from where you can trigger the s3 download. In download.php before authenticating the download check the key is valid and make it invalid after the first click.